# How to make sshpass work from shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sshpass

There are multiple servers with same username and password. So, i am trying to automate ssh via script.

So, i wrote

```
user='user'
pass='#pR3z1X!@'
ip=$1

sshpass -p $pass ssh $user@$ip
```

This is not working. I am getting

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I dont have sudo user rights, otherwise I would have done it by using sudo.
But when I try manually

```
sshpass -p '#pR3z1X!@' ssh user@1.1.1.1
```

it works!

Does anyone know, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Your script has some quoting bugs, but none of them should cause the behavior at hand. A good place to start would to run your script with `set -x` debugging enabled. If, for example, `$1` doesn't have the value you think it has, that'll make it obvious.

Comment: To find those quoting bugs, http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend. Also, it's quite possible that your file may have DOS newlines rather than UNIX ones -- that would explain your values (password included) being passed wrong -- but it'll be obvious in the `set -x` output, so no matter what, that's the direction you want to start from..

Comment: Also, while I'm sure you've seen this advice all over whatever resources you googled before asking questions here, _using sshpass is a bad idea_. RSA key authentication is much more secure, _especially_ if your key is escrowed in a TPM, Yubikey, smartcard, or somewhere else it can't be copied out from. You can install a key on the server with only permission to run one specific command, whereas in general, a password to an account means 100% control over that account.

Comment: (btw, why would you try using sudo? The problem is with the remote system not authenticating you; nothing to do with the local system. Treating sudo as magic pixie dust that gets sprinkled on any kind of auth error to just make it go away causes other, much more serious problems -- like files that should be owned by your user account instead being owned by root, thus forcing you to use sudo _more_ because your user account can't access files that it ought to own).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ... Thanks for the detailed comments. The mentioned code is just only a part of the script file. $1 is validated above the request. I am performing sshpass on local ips within the servers (that cant be reached from outside). shellcheck.net helped me. I missed quoting the variables. Adding double quotes around the vairables fixed the issue.